# Assets access path in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, capybara, assets

In development/test mode I add following in config/environments/*.rb:

```
config.assets.paths << "whatever_path"
```

When I start webrick, image at "whatever_path/collections/image.jpg" is accessible through this path:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/assets/collections/image.jpg
```

How (without fs manipulation) can I make it accessible through this path:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/collections/image.jpg
```

I need this redirect to work only in test mode.

Comment: So just to make this clear, you want to be able to directly access images on a specific route? You'll find for file attachments in production that you will need to use a gem like `paperclip`. Can I ask why you need to do this?

Comment: i process videos with external tool and extract their thumbnails. in testing mode however i don't want to create those thumbnails (only factorygirl objects), so i just want to provide dummy thumbnails. otherwise i get lot of routingerrors while running tests with capybara (and i dont want to simply suppress these errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative solution to my problem, i added following in features/support/asset_host.rb

```
ActionController::Base.asset_host = Proc.new { |source|
  true if source["/collections"] and File.exists?(Rails.root.join("whatever_path",source[1..-1]))
}
```

this suppresses the error only if file exists in dummy fs at whatever_path